# Determine model and manufacturer of Windows Mobile/CE device

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-ce

We're running our generic mobile application for Windows Mobile / CE on a couple of devices (Motorola, Honeywell, ...) and would like to automatically detect on which device we're running. Currently, we need to configure which device service to use (e.g. for scanning), but we would like to automate that process.

Is there a reliable way to determine the manufacturer and the model of a device on Windows Mobile / CE (e.g. "Motorola MC3190" or "Honeywell Dolphin 6100")?

What we've already tried:

- Get OEM info via `SystemParametersInfo` (throws exception on some devices)
- Looked at the OpenNETCF API (which seems to use `SystemParametersInfo` as well)

I'd prefer not to guess the device type by analyzing the serial number, the file system layout, or the CPU.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no standard enforced for Windows Mobile OEMs to provide such info. If HKLM\ident and HKLM\Platform do not offer enough info, you have to look for other unique device identification items.

I am using a manufacturer dependent file, for example: "\Windows\itc50.dll" for Intermec devices.

Comment: Thanks for the hints on `HKLM\ident` and `HKLM\Platform` ... very useful!